# Using ParseDelimitedFromCodedInputStream for reading from file?

Tags: c++, file, stream, protocol-buffers

I have a file with multiple protobuf messages in it, and look-up-table telling me where which message starts in the file. The messages are written delimited.

In C#, I can just do something like

```
fileStream.Position = message_start_index;
ProtoMessage msg = ProtoMessage.Parser.ParseDelimitedFrom(fileStream);
```

and be done.

For C++, the `ParseDelimitedFrom` and `SerializeDelimitedTo` functions have been finally added to the library, so I was excited not having to take care of the delimiters manually anymore.

But for parsing delimited messages, there are only `ParseDelimitedFromZeroCopyStream` and `ParseDelimitedFromCodedStream` - both some special implemenations by google.

How do I get a standard `ifstream` or `istream` in there?

I tried just passing it, casting it, looked for constructors of those special stream types to read from a normal stream, but could not find anything that works, so any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protobuf API makes heavy use of inheritance, so instead of looking at the constructors of `ZeroCopyInputStream` and `CodedInputStream`, you should be looking for their subclasses.

The one you are looking for is [`google::protobuf::io::IstreamInputStream`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.zero_copy_stream_impl#IstreamInputStream), a subclass of `google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyInputStream` that adapts a `std::istream`.

You can use it like so:

```
std::ifstream my_file("path/to/file");
google::protobuf::io::IstreamInputStream zc_stream(&my_file);

ParseDelimitedFromZeroCopyStream(&msg, &zc_stream, nullptr);
```